# mysql display database data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, comments

I'm trying to display comments on my site from my database. I know that my connection is working, as shown by $test (which displays "Array").

How do I convert the array into usable information? This is my best shot, but it doesn't display anything:

```
<?php
$connect;

$sql_get_topic_info = "SELECT * FROM wall ORDER BY time ASC"; 
$res_get_comments_info = mysql_query($sql_get_comments_info); 
$num_get_comments_info = mysql_numrows($res_get_comments_info); 
$test = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql_get_topic_info)); //just to make sure the connection is working
echo $test; //displays "Array"


//Runs comment loop 
$i=0; 
while ($i < $num_get_comments_info) { 

$sel_comments_info_time = mysql_result($res_get_comments_info,$i,"time"); 
$sel_comments_info_message = mysql_result($res_get_comments_info,$i,"message"); 
$sel_comments_info_company = mysql_result($res_get_comments_info,$i,"company"); 

echo "<li>Company: $sel_comments_info_company<br/>"; 
echo "Comment: $sel_comments_info_message <br/>";
echo "$sel_comments_info_time"; 
echo "</li>"; 

$i++; 
} 
?>
```

Updated script: (from answer below)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT company, message FROM wall");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
printf ("company: %s  message: %s", $row["company"], $row["message"]);
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

which prints:

```
company: company 1 message: message 1company: company 2 message: message 2company: company 3 message: message 3
```

Comment: Is `$num_get_comments_info` something greater than 0?

Comment: Well, I have about 15 rows in the database, but when I try to print $num_get_comments_info, nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage of `mysql_` is discouraged, you should be using [`mysqli_`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) functions instead.

From [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) documentation:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM mytable");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("ID: %s  Name: %s", $row[0], $row[1]);  
}
```

Use `print_r($test)` to see the array to see its format. Then you can use the loop above to display the parts of it in whatever order you want. Each column from your database is in the resulting row

```
row = [col1, col2, col3...]
```

You can access them using array indices `$row[0], $row[1]...`. You can see the order by either looking at the order of columns in the database or seeing what it is in the `print_r`. Then you can just echo it out in the order you want.

Comment: If nothing is showing, there might be errors... check error log?

Comment: awesome. I am able to print the data just fine. I just was wondering how to break it up so I can display the first row of data, then add my own text, then the second row, and so on... Below is my updated script:

Comment: You can use line breaks `<br />` to put stuff on a new line and even include your HTML in the `printf`.

Comment: FYI you should be editing your question with updates, not posting answers. I took care of it for you this time. You should delete your answer.